# How to change the SDR channel definition of IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq

I need to change the `CONNAME('xx.xx.xxx.xx(1414)` to `CONNAME('yy.yy.yyy.yy(1414)` for IBM MQ. I searched through the internet I did not found any command. My object definition code is given below.

```
DEFINE CHANNEL(CHANNELNAME) +
       CHLTYPE(SDR) +
       TRPTYPE(TCP) +
       MAXMSGL(30000000) +
       DESCR('Channel to REPLY TO sender') +
       XMITQ('Sender.XMITQ') +
       CONNAME('xx.xx.xxx.xx(1414)') +
       BATCHSZ(50) +
       DISCINT(6000) +
       SHORTRTY(10) +
       SHORTTMR(60) +
       LONGRTY(999999999) +
       KAINT(AUTO)   +
       LONGTMR(1200) +
       SEQWRAP(999999999) +
       CONVERT(YES) +
       MCATYPE(PROCESS) +
       HBINT(300) +
       BATCHINT(0) +
       NPMSPEED(FAST)
```

Can I use the `ALTER` command? if I delete the channel and redefine it will it cause any problem to existing channels and queues?

Comment: Read: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q085170_.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ALTER CHANNEL` command like this:-

```
ALTER CHANNEL(CHANNELNAME) CHLTYPE(SDR) CONNAME('yy.yy.yyy.yy(1414)')
```

You only need to supply the attributes that you need to change, plus always the `CHLTYPE`.

You don't need to `DELETE` and re-`DEFINE` the channel object, and doing so would cause the run-time state such as channel sequence numbers to get out of step.

**Additional Reading**

- [ALTER CHANNEL reference documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.adm.doc/q085170_.htm)